# Flag if previous entry differs from next across two colums

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to flag instances where consecutive entries in column 1 are the same but consecutive entries in column 5 are not the same. I want to flag this in a new column using '1' and '0'.

**An example:**

[image: An example]

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Make it easy to help you! https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. The entries are not numeric figures, they are text

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: "previous", "next", "consecutive" are all words relating to *ordering*. So lets be clear on how we determine the order - is it based on the `AUD_Date` column?

Comment: "I want" doesn't give me the feel of someone asking for help

Comment: Also, we much prefer sample data as *text* (preferably a `declare @sample table (...) insert @sample (..) values (...),(...),(...)` pair of statements). We can copy and paste such samples into a query window and start working on a solution. We can't do that with an image, and we don't really need the typing practice.

Answer (score 0):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no next or previous row unless a column specifies the ordering.

There are two ways to interpret your question:

1. You want examples where `col1` has more than one value than `col5`.
2. You have a column that specifies ordering.

In both cases, you can use window functions.  For the first:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             min(col5) over (partition by col1) as min_col5,
             max(col5) over (partition by col1) as max_col5
      from t
     ) t
where min_col5 <> max_col5;
```

Note that this returns all rows with the `col1` value.

For the second, you would use `lead()`/`lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(col5) over (partition by col1 order by ?) as prev_col5,
             lead(col5) over (partition by col1 order by ?) as next_col5
      from t
     ) t
where col5 <> prev_col5 or col5 <> next_col5;
```

The `?` is for the ordering column.

Note that this returns the two rows you have highlighted.